# What are things i can do myself to keep mobile home from falling apart until i can get money to repair

Tags: trailer

I live in an **Old** mobile home.  I am a  53 year old female, single and  some what mechanical. I have a very limited (*low*) budget.

The walls, inside and out, are coming apart and the cracks are getting wider. The cold is coming thru and the floor is separating.

Things that need attention; roof, walls, wiring, floors. Everything from A to Z, but all that requires money I don't have at moment.

What, if any, are little things I can do to hold it together until I can do better. I have basic tools and can do some things myself.

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: As much as we'd love to help you, this question is _far_ too broad and opinion based. Please pick a project that you believe is _your_ highest priority, then ask specific, detailed questions about it (you can [edit] this one to be more specific), including pictures of the problem area and your plan to fix it. We can then help you address that specific issue. If it would require more money than you can spend right now, that's OK, you have a plan for the future. Pick a different project and ask about that...

Comment: I want to underline what @FreeMan said: we're here to help, and we WANT to help, but we need to do so in the way the site was designed. So, [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here, and then come back with more focused questions.

Answer (score 2):

Post an add on craigslist in  the barter section,  just ask if if there are any kind souls who may have time to assist you in doing some upkeep.

There are people in the world that are kind and willing to help. I see posts on craigslist occasionally from folks offering to help the more money challenged of us.

Since money is tight is there anything such as skills, talents, things or space you can offer in trade to a handyman?

Maybe reach out to local civic groups or church's.

Your question is very broad and we can not really give specific advise on each thing with out a very detailed description of the problem. If you have   questions  about specific issues you can post  about each of them  to ask   if it is something you can do yourself with a minimal investment of materials.

Answer (score 0):

### The "little things" are chapters of learning

Generally, success in crafts like this relies on 3 ingredients:

- Learning how to do it.
- The audacity to overcome self-doubt
- An extra dose of learning to get it right.

So you shouldn't miss an opportunity to learn more about the crafts you need to save your home. **The point is, become a person who creates**.  And whatever else wastes your time, dump it. Get rid of cable TV for instance, it's a high expense and drains your brain. You're better off watching Youtube videos of people who do it successfully.

In fact, [this one makes a pretty good argument](https://youtu.be/g-B_9Xzy9ds?t=460) that anyone can, and that certainly applies to all humans.  I cued it up at 7:40, but you can rewind or play parts [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOOXmfkXpkM) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2ejcEddQt8) or Brooke's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSRWAIn4G88) on the build.

Never stop learning. Never get frustrated and quit.  Know that human beings are meant to be able to be self-sufficient.  That's why we have the ability to learn.  So use it! It is a gift.